# How to bind to the ItemsSource of a DataDrid from inside DataRow?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm working with a window with several DataGrid's, and I'd like to process deletion event via a single command.

For this, I need to pass to that command the list of records, from which the record has to be deleted.

Here's what I mean:

```
<DataGrid  Margin="0" HeadersVisibility="None" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding GroupExtednedDataList}" 
     ... >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="delete" 
           CommandParameter="{Binding::: 
          How do I bind from here to GroupExtednedDataList from ItemsSoruce?}" >
                        </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

How do I bind from inside `<Button Content="delete"` to ItemsSource of the DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```xml
{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}
```